# locate a html link address string in a list

Tags: python

I have a list named 'aList'

```
[
"<a href='a.html?dataset=1'><tt>outputs</tt></a></td>\n", 
"<a href='a.html?dataset=1'><tt>outputs</tt></a></td>\n", 
"<a href='a.html?dataset=1'><tt>outputs</tt></a></td>\n", 
"<img src='folder.gif' alt='folder'> &nbsp;<a href='catalog.html'><tt>test all files in a directory/</tt></a></td>\n", 
"<img src='/thredds/folder.gif' alt='folder'> &nbsp;<a href='enhancedcatalog.html'><tt>test enhanced catalog/</tt></a></td>\n",
"<hr size='1' noshade='noshade'><h3><a href='/abc/catalog.html'>abc</a> at <a href='http://www.abcd.com/'>csiro</a> see <a href='/abcd/serverinfo.html'> info </a><br>\n", 
"data server [version 4.6.10 - 2017-04-19t16:32:55-0600] <a href='http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/reference/index.html'> documentation</a></h3>\n"
]
```

I want to retrieve all html link like the below

```
a.html?dataset=1
catalog.html
enhancedcatalog.html
/abcd/serverinfo.html
http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/reference/index.html
```

I have tried but it didn't return an expected result. Please give some advice.

```
matching = [s for s in aList if ".html" in s]
print(matching)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression or use BeautifulSoup to get the href values in a html. here i've given code using regular expression. Hope it helps you

```
urls=set()
for link in aList:
    urls.update(re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', link))
for url in urls: 
    print(url)
```

Output

> /abcd/serverinfo.html
>   enhancedcatalog.html
>   http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/reference/index.html
>   http://www.abcd.com/
>   a.html?dataset=1
>   catalog.html
>   /abc/catalog.html